# only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices Neural Networks

Tags: python, numpy

I get the following error for the code.

> Error only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis
>   (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

```
w, b =initialize_with_zeros(X_train.shape[0])

# Gradient descent (≈ 1 line of code)
parameters, grads, costs = optimize(w, b, X_train, Y_train, num_iterations, learning_rate, print_cost)

# Retrieve parameters w and b from dictionary "parameters"
w = parameters["w"]
b = parameters["b"]

# Predict test/train set examples (≈ 2 lines of code)
Y_prediction_test = predict(w, b, X_test)
Y_prediction_train = predict(w, b, X_train)

### END CODE HERE ###

# Print train/test Errors
print("train accuracy: {} %".format(100 - np.mean(np.abs(Y_prediction_train - Y_train)) * 100))
print("test accuracy: {} %".format(100 - np.mean(np.abs(Y_prediction_test - Y_test)) * 100))


d = {"costs": costs,
     "Y_prediction_test": Y_prediction_test, 
     "Y_prediction_train" : Y_prediction_train, 
     "w" : w, 
     "b" : b,
     "learning_rate" : learning_rate,
     "num_iterations": num_iterations}

return d

index = 1
plt.imshow(test_set_x[:,index].reshape((num_px, num_px, 3)))

print ("y = " + str(test_set_y[0,index]) + ", you predicted that it is a \"" 
+ classes[d["Y_prediction_test"][0,index]].decode("utf-8") +  "\" picture.")
```

Comment: When you ask about an error you need to indicate clearly where it occurs.  That may be require posting all or part of the traceback.  You need to identify which indexing operation is causing the problem.  Check the type of the object being indexed (such as `ndarray`), and check the indices.  My guess is you are using a string or floats.

Comment: I see several indexing operations in that expression.  Which is giving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index has to be `int`:

```
print ("y = " + str(test_set_y[0, int(index)]) + ", you predicted that it is a \"" + classes[int(d["Y_prediction_test"][0,index])].decode("utf-8") +  "\" picture.")
```